# Is WHERE and HAVING clause possible without GROUP BY clause in SQL?

Tags: sql, group-by, where-clause, having

Suppose I'm writing as query for the aggregate functions where I want result based on some conditions both on the column of the table and on aggregate function. So is it possible to use WHERE and HAVING clause to get expected result without GROUP BY clause.

I wrote following query for the above condition.

```
select *
from ORDER_DETAILS 
where item_price > 1000
having count(item) >= 5 ;
```

Comment: You can't use `HAVING` without `GROUP BY`. What's wrong with using an aggregation?

Comment: You can actually have a HAVING but no GROUP BY, but it rarely never makes any sense. (Anyway, the solution here is something else.)

Comment: A [mcve] would make things clearer. I.e. show us some sample table data and also the expected result - all as formatted text (no images, no links.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `having` just like `where`, but can apply to aggregate function results.
You should keep track of the data **rows** and **columns** after each clause.
If we name a `row_id` property that can be used to locate one single row of a table. Then the `where` clause doesn't change the `row_id`.
When we use aggregate functions, it implies *input multi rows and get a single result*, that changes the `row_id`.In fact no `group by` clause means everything go to one bucket, and the output result only have one row.
My best guess is that you want to get original data rows, which have some attributes that passes aggregated value check.Eg found order details that *item price>1000*(origin filter) and *more than 5 items in single order*(aggregated filter).
So `group + aggregate + having` give you aggregated filter dataset, you can `join` this dataset back to origin table, then the result table have same `row_id` with original ORDER_DETAILS

```sql
select *
from ORDER_DETAILS 
where item_price > 1000
and order_id in (
  select order_id 
  from ORDER_DETAILS 
  group by order_id 
  having count(item) >= 5
);
```

Note：

- order_id is the aggregated filter column example
- I use `in subquery` for convenience, you can change it into `join`
- If you are working with big data sql, like hive/spark, you can also use `window` functions to get the aggregate result on each row of original table.

Comment: Answer is pretty good but I don't want to use subquery or join and in final result I don't need original data rows. I want hat whether the event happens just now is matched with above mentioned criteria or not. So, Is there any other way to match this both conditions?

Comment: @AbhishekGJoshi Just what to check `if there is >1000 price item bought, and there is more than 5 item in table`, just `select 1...` and check whether theres is a result(not empty set).Notice: `count(item)` means how many not-null item values, not distinct item values, use `count(distinct item)` for latter purpose.